# Joining 2D tracking markers with an offset

Tags: video, tracking

Is there any way to join tracks with an offset (like can be done in After effects)?  I'm looking for a way to create a gap less 2D track. (It will be used only for 2D stabilization)

This is an example showing the situation in the footage.
[image: example footage]

Here are the two tracked marks that get blocked by a pole at different times.
[image: my two trackers]

I want to be able to use the tracking data from the black mark when the red mark is obstructed.
[image: red tracker blocked]

However if I simply join the two tracks there will be a jump in the path.

Comment: You can use 2 trackers, one that track forward and another track backward and then select both and join with Ctrl+J

Comment: Or before the tracker gets to the obstacle select the tracker with RMB with G button to offset it back and continue tracking untill you can see the tracked area again.

Comment: @Denis I can not join the two tracks, because there will be a jump in the resulting motion path when the tracker switches between the red and the black marks.

Comment: look in Track properties panel in Merker section, you can set the offset there when your tracking area is blocked or use RMB+G to offset the marker and move it back when you can see the tracked area.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To track areas that are blocked by obstacles or temporary going off-screen. Move the tracking marker before the area is hidden by pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and dragging the marker to another tracking point, or offsetting the marker in *Track properties panel* in *Marker section* by changing X and Y offset position. You can then continue tracking the scene under the offset tracking area until the original tracking area is visible again, then move the marker back using the same procedure.

[image: tracking marker settings]

Comment: I realise this answer is very old, but can anyone say why this is preferable (if it is) to disabling the tracker and then re-enabling it once the originally tracked point comes back into view/frame?