# Bad Camera solve in blender with forground motion

Tags: camera, tracking

I have a scene I'm trying to track, but I'm unable to get a good camera solve. I end up with errors above 1.46. The issue with that scene is that there is an actor moving in the scene. So I'm tracking the half of the frame which the actor doesn't cross. Is there a specific strategy to get a good camera solve with scenes like this?

Here is a link to the scene I'm trying to track. Any suggestions would be great.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0By7_pLesGvS0VkFodE9DMXRHNU0?usp=sharing

thanks in advance.

Comment: this related question may help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42329/19287

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset:and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73855/motion-tracking-objects-that-go-out-of-frame-and-re-enter-later/73868#73868

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at those. But I think what's different in my case is that I have a foreground moving actor. So I'm unable to track the entire frame, just the portion of the frame which the actor doesn't overlap with. Would tracking half of the frame represent an issue? IE, the track won't understand the motion of the camera correctly?

Comment: I ended up using Voodoo, which was remarkably accurate, and completely automatic. It's a good alternative if one can't get an accurate track from within blender.