# Motion tracking: the tracker goes out of frame but then won't reappear?

Tags: camera, video, tracking

So my problem is basicly *this*: [Motion Tracking objects that go out of frame and re-enter later](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73855/motion-tracking-objects-that-go-out-of-frame-and-re-enter-later)

**But** the difference is that my markers move out of frame because of the motion of the camera, but **they don't reappear in the scene again**. So they move out, but don't come back.
I can't solve the camera motion like this since i never have the amount of trackers in one frame.

What should I do?
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If you don't have a section of the video with at least 8 trackers you won't be able to solve the scene. It is hard to help you without seeing the video. Can you post a link to it? A possible solution would be to offset a tracker (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset) but that would only work if the tracked area is in the same plane and there are no major distortions in the lens.

Comment: read also this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking/27656#27656

Comment: and also this long list of tips for successful motion tracking: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332