# People walking through camera tracking

Tags: animation, camera, tracking

I’ve just started to teach myself about camera tracking in blender. I’ve watched tutorials and everything shows an animated 3D object in the middle of an open space. Can you do and get the same effect with something passing in front of the animated object during the scene? if so, how? Thanks

Comment: In fact YES, tracking points could be hidden when not on scene so Blender will not use them for some time (for example moving object crossing them) and use others instead. Dunno if it works when ALL points hidden but its a very special case imo. This video shows how to "treat" hidden points... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzym73lhmD4

Comment: Related: [joining 2D tracking markers with an offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset) and [motion trackin objects that co out of frame and re-enter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73855/motion-tracking-objects-that-go-out-of-frame-and-re-enter-later/73868#73868)

Comment: and: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14704/camera-tracking-moving-the-camera-too-much/14713#14713

Comment: And read a comprehensive post on motion tracking here: [**How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Answer (score 2):

If the point you are tracking gets obscured, think of it in two sections, tracking before and tracking after.

1. Track the early footage until your marker is obscured
2. Jump forward until it is visible again
3. Move the marker back into place
4. Track forward through the later footage

[image: early track]

[image: later track]

If objects that you are adding should also be obscured, you will want to either track some points on the obstruction and make them the parent of a mask or keyframe the position of the mask to follow the obstruction through the shot. You then use the mask to cut out your objects in the render.

[image: mask node]

Instead of moving the marker into position after it reappears, you can also track the point with a new marker, these two markers can then be selected and merged into one using Join Tracks.

[image: Join tracks]