# motion tracking - is there a way to automatically clear tracks after they leave the frame?

Tags: video, tracking, motion-capture

hi there I am tracking a video with many tracking points to decrease solve error.

many of them leave the frame by the end of the video. is it possible in anyway to automatically clear track data after they dissapear from the frame?

or is the only way to go one by one, find the frame when they dissapear, and press clear track?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure, it should be possible to script this in python.

Comment: any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an automatic way.

You could try  changing the Correlation or Margin settings to make a tracker fail earlier, so that it stops and doesn't continue tracking with errors on the edge of frame.

[image]
Otherwise

Go to the frame where you have the last accurately tracked item and press delete forward (or back if you are tracking backwards).

[image]

Another way to deal with elements on the edge of frame (or when an object is temporarily blocked) is to offset the tracker, so that you can use other elements to continue tracking.

See: [Joining 2D tracking markers with an offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset)

Blender has great tracking tools, but they do require a lot of work and manual and constant supervision.

Keep in mind that you don't need a large number of tracking points (at least 8 for sure), but what matters is that the tracking is **accurate**. There are times where more tracking points can also be detrimental for the camera solution.

If you haven't done already read:

[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)