# How to motion track films where track points get out of screen?

Tags: tracking

Situation, a quadcopter drone video, it flies 500m away with a view corners moves  then does 360 turn and flies back. I want to camera track this, but the trackpoints get out of view after a short while. How to camera track longer video files, where trackpoints gets lost (out screen) after a while ?.

This problem was not related to the sugestion not a duplicate i found a different solution meanwhile.
I f someone removes the possible duplication mark i might be able to post the solution here.

Comment: I recommend watching the motion tracking series by CGMatter, which covers complex trackings tasks among many helpful tips: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLSGG7sDEac https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrlxssjYeZU https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJ2zONKJ2Uk

Comment: Read also: [Joining 2D tracking markers with an offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset)

Comment: And : [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)