# Is it possible to get a camera solve of large camera dolly?

Tags: camera, tracking

I shot this footage of the beach from inside my car and i am trying to 3D track it and get some camera solve but blender doesn't seem to recognize the movement at all. I alway get huge solve erros and the camera doesent seen to move at all inside 3D viewport.
The Footage:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-F5k8WtR528

Comment: Related: [how to camera track complex shots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210836/how-to-camera-track-complex-shoots/210871#210871)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can track a shot like that, as long as you decide to put some effort into it.

The shot has enough information to create 3d information, as it clearly shows parallax. You should be able to get a pretty accurate reconstruction out of it.

The most important part is that you track the island in the far background (and maybe some clouds that show enough contrast on the edges),  then parts of the middle ground (the metal bars on the beach) and close elements on the street. The elements that are in the foreground close to the camera are going to be the hardest elements to track, since they move too fast, so you will need large search boxes for the tracker. You will need to track a lot of different points in the street, that come in and out of the frame.

Place your trackers manually, don't rely on the autodetect features of blender. You shouldn't track moving elements like the waves.

3d reconstruction works by estimating the placement of points in the 3d world by computing the changes of the objects on the images. Objects that are close to the camera move faster than those far away. Computing the difference in speed, blender can determine if objects are close or far, and where the camera is with respect to the objects.

Blender's 3d tracking capabilities are quite sophisticated, but you need to understand how to make them work for you. The most important aspect is that **tracking is done as accurate as possible**.

You will need to babysit the trackers and make sure they are not slipping or tracking unwanted features.

The most challenging  aspect of this shot are the elements that are occluded by passing objects (the bicycle, the palm trees will block the island, etc). Those blocked elements need to be tracked in different segments when the elements are visible, and then have the trackers joined, so that blender understand that it is dealing with the same element. Other elements can be tracked using offset.

[image]

confused?

Read **very carefully** trough the following links (yes, all of the text), all the information you need is there:

[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

and [Joining 2D tracking markers with an offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset/28826#28826)

Comment: Omg man! thank you much, you rekindled hope for a newbie! kkk. I have as matter of fact babysit the tracker but i had no idea about the importance of the background tracker points like the island.

I think what is learned here's to never give up, many thanks once again!

Comment: Yes, not giving up is important, but learning how to use the tools will make it less frustrating. Good luck on your project.