# How to camera track complex shoots?

Tags: camera, tracking

I am not able to this shoot
https://youtu.be/PkEsl5c5nC4.
The starting is good but then it diverges.

These are my trackers and error is 0.41
[image]
this is my hold out material because I need the scene to be there
[image]
See that a slight diversion!!
[image]

I tried some tricks I saw on YouTube like reducing the weight of some bad tracks and using the refine options.

Comment: Please read other question on this site: you have to explain exactly what your problem is (not just "it doesn't work") and what have you tried so far. Have you studied the good old Track Match Blend tut?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1v-Bf9XOXIg&list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g

Comment: Sorry let me do that

Comment: Thanks for the editing, it's slightly better now. What's the difference between the two bottom images?

Comment: Related: [is it possible to get a camera solve of large camera dolly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182170/is-it-possible-to-get-a-camera-solve-of-large-camera-dolly/182176#182176)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Comment: @RobertGützkow this question was closed as lacking details, but it is clear and the elements to answer are provided, it is a duplicate, but can the reasons for close be changed?

Comment: sorry i i added the same screenshot twice.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the video, it makes it much easier to help you.

Your shot is by no means a complex shot. Even though your camera barely moves, there is plenty of information there.

To effectively reconstruct the scene you need to pay attention to ***[parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax)***, meaning paying attention to how **tracked elements that are close to the camera move at different speeds in the frame, than those elements that are far away**.

The elements that are close to the camera and the furthest ones are the most useful to reconstruct 3D space.

The emphasis should be in trying to accurately track elements that are in fixed in real life, but at different distances from the camera. You effort should be in tracking elements in foreground, middle and background.

In this particular case add more tracking points on the cracks on the walls and the railing, as well as features in the lamp post behind the child, and then the background buildings and, most importantly: in the tree behind the building (which seems to be the object that is the farthest away). Don't track any of the cables, as they don't really have any distinctive features.

[image]

One more thing that is crucial in this kind of shots, that use a wide angle lens very close to the subject, is to determine the ***lens distortion*** correctly.

Please take a few minutes to read very carefully through the comprehensive post on motion tracking on this same site, to understand how to make better use the tools that will help you reconstruct the scene:

## [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Comment: Thank you will definitely try that and let you know.